# Javascript Json output with slash "/"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have this function using json and jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/7z4w6jxt/

```
var data = {"offset":0,"results":[{"link_1/_text":"kebahagiaan","link_3":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?p=414","link_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?tag=kebahagiaan","link_2":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?tag=meditasi","link_3/_text":"Meditasi: Makna Rasa Sakit","title_text":"Meditasi: Makna Rasa Sakit","text_2":"Semua manusia yang hidup di dunia ini ingin merasakan kebahagiaan, dalam bentuk apapun.","link_2/_text":"meditasi"},{"link_1/_text":"memberi dan menerima","link_3":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?p=411","link_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?tag=memberi-dan-menerima","link_2":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?tag=men-2","link_3/_text":"Take and Give","title_text":"Take and Give","text_2":"Untuk beberapa alasan yang sulit dimengerti, alam telah membagi pria dan wanita dalam sebuah perbedaan sikap dalam memandang sebuah hal.","link_2/_text":"men"},{"link_1/_text":"10 saran jika ingin menyatakan cinta","link_3":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?p=404","link_1":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?tag=10-saran-jika-ingin-menyatakan-cinta","link_2":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?tag=menyatakan-cinta","link_3/_text":"10 Saran Bagi Wanita Untuk Menyatakan Cinta Lebih Dulu","title_text":"10 Saran Bagi Wanita Untuk Menyatakan Cinta Lebih Dulu","text_2":"Apakah anda pernah menyukai seorang pria, dan dilihat dari gelagatnya sepertinya dia juga menyukai anda?","link_2/_text":"menyatakan cinta"}],"cookies":[],"connectorVersionGuid":"ed0ce142-861e-4d2e-bacd-3dd1de491a69","connectorGuid":"d6d21746-2d8f-4980-b1ec-8e1a5d52b133","pageUrl":"http://pmj.astaga.com/article/?page_id=709"};


$(data.results).each(function() {
    var output = "<p>" + this.link_1_text + "</p>";
    $('#placeholder').append(output);
});
```

i just wanna print one data that from this "link_1/_text":"kebahagiaan"
that is **kebahagiaan**

can you explain to me how it should be?

Thankyou

Comment: Use the indexer based syntax `this["link_1/_test"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z4w6jxt/1/)

You can use the indexer based syntax to get the result you want like this:

```
"<p>" + this["link_1/_text"] + "</p">
```

In JavaScript, objects act as a kind of key/value store so you can access the property name directly through a string. While you can access them with the dot `.` notation, it does not allow you to do so with characters that are invalid in a variable name.

A great use of this which makes code reflection easier is if you have a string containing the name of the property you want to retrieve.

[Here's a little example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lu789rta/)

HTML

```
<div id="placeholder"> 
</div>
<input type="text" id="key" />
<button type="button" id="clicker">Submit</button>
```

Script

```
var data = {
    prop1: "The value of property 1!",
    prop2: "The value of property 2!",
    prop3: "The value of property 3!",
}

$('#clicker').on('click', function(){

    // Get the user input
    var input = $('#key').val(); 

    // Retrieve the property using the user input string
    var output = data[input];

    // Placeholder object
    var ph = $('#placeholder'); 

    if(typeof output === 'undefined'){
        // There is no property that matches the user input string
        ph.html('Oops that property doesnt exist!');
    }
    else{
        // There is a property, so lets write the value of it.
        ph.html(output);
    }
});
```

This basically takes the user input and outputs the property matching that string.

This example is not very valuable, but the technique itself is quite useful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer
$(data.results).each(function() {

```
var output = "<p>" + this["link_1/_text"] + "</p>";
$('#placeholder').append(output);
```

});